# js, как в строке в каждом слове сделать первую букву в верхний регистр?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

как в строке в каждом слове сделать первую букву в верхний регистр ?
Точнее как сделать это регуляркой ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let str = 'исходная Строка дЛЯ теста';

let res = str.replace(/(?:^|\s)(\S)/ug, m => m.toUpperCase());

console.log(res);
```

- `(?:^|\s)` - начало строки или пробельный символ
- `(\S)` - непробельный символ с захватом для замены

Насколько я знаю, в js regexp нет аналога `\b` для unicode.

---

В некоторых случаях, эта регулярка не подойдёт(из-за отсутствия пробелов): `а,б,в`

Проще всего использовать класс `\p{L}`:

```js
let str = 'исходная Строка дЛЯ теста(раз,два,три)';

let res = str.replace(/(?:^|[^\p{L}])(\p{L})/ug, m => m.toUpperCase());

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если среда поддерживает стандарт ECMAScript 2018, можно использовать `(?<![\p{L}\p{N}_])` в качестве альтернативы границе слова `\b` и `\p{Ll}` для поиска любой буквы в нижнем регистре (`\p{L}` найдет любые буквы, которые уже могут быть в верхнем регистре):

```js
var rx = /(?<![\p{L}\p{N}_])\p{Ll}/gu;
var s = "наша новая,короткая строка.и тут ещё предложение.";
console.log(s.replace(rx, $0 => $0.toUpperCase()));
```

- `(?<![\p{L}\p{N}_])` - блок предварительного просмотра назад, находит место в строке, перед которым нет буквы, цифры или `_`
- `\p{Ll}` - буква в нижнем регистре.

Если нет поддержки ECMAScript 2018, нужна либо библиотека XRegExp, либо выражение, содержащее диапазоны поддерживаемых букв:

```js
var rx = /(?:^|[^а-яА-ЯёЁA-Za-z0-9_])[a-zа-яё]/gu;
var s = "наша новая,короткая строка.and another sentence.";
console.log(s.replace(rx, function($0) { return $0.toUpperCase(); }));

var xrx = XRegExp("(?:^|[^\\pL\\pN_])\\p{Ll}", "g");
console.log(XRegExp.replace(s, rx, function($0) { return $0.toUpperCase(); }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```